# How to iterate through XML and create array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsxmlparser

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I'm having the user input a city, which I'm then plugging into Yahoo's Placefinder.  Here's an XML file with "Springfield" entered as a test city.

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?city=springfield

As you can see, Yahoo nicely provides a number of how many cities it found.  So, next I wanted to take each city found, take `line2`, `line4`, and `woeid` and store them in an array.  So, the array would look like this (with two cities for example)...

```
      -> line1
City1 -> line2
      -> woeid


      -> line1
City2 -> line2
      -> woeid
```

Then, I wanted to take this array and display it in a `UITableView`, with the WOEID hidden.  When one of the cities is selected, I need to take the selected city's WOEID and use it.

I was thinking of using an instance of `NSXMLParser` to do this.

**EDIT:** Perhaps this question is too broad.  Maybe if I could just get some help with parsing the XML and adding to an array.  Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to sit down with Apple's tutorial's and sample code, then come back with specific questions. What you want to do isn't hard, but answering is more than an SE answer.

Comment: I do understand it's too broad.  Perhaps I could get some help on just the first part, then.  Parsing the XML and adding it to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a DOM parser instead `NSXMLParser` (SAX based parser), because that makes it much easier to construct the array.

You could use libxml2 (included in iPhone SDK), [TouchXML](https://github.com/schwa/TouchXML), [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) or [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html).

Comment: I've had some experience with `TBXML`.  So, if I used it, how would I add the data I needed to an array?

Comment: TBXML is good - simply go through the children for each city node in a loop, and add them to an array one by one.  Although now that I look at the data again, why not create City objects that hold line1/line2/woeID data?

Comment: I guess I could do that.  I just don't know how (using TBXML) to find the next `<Result>`.  Is there a method in `TBXML` (maybe something like `sibling named`) that goes to the next `Result` object?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a sample `NSXMLParser` application at their website that could be of use to you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing.  Posting here to help anyone else out if they have the same problem.  ***[Here](http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?city=sunnyfield)*** is a sample XML that could be parsed using this method.

```
-(void)someMethod {

 TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:YOURURLHERE] retain];

 cityArray = [NSMutableArray array];
 [cityArray retain];
 if (tbxml.rootXMLElement)
 [self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
 [tbxml release];
}

- (void)traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element {
 do {
  if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"Found"]) {
   NSLog(@"Number of found items: %@",[TBXML textForElement:element]);
  }

  if (element->firstChild) 
            [self traverseElement:element->firstChild];

  if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"Result"]) {
   TBXMLElement *cityName = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"line2" parentElement:element];
   TBXMLElement *country = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"country" parentElement:element];
   TBXMLElement *woeid = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"woeid" parentElement:element];

   NSArray *city = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[TBXML textForElement:cityName],
        [TBXML textForElement:country],
        [TBXML textForElement:woeid],nil];

   [cityArray addObject:city];   
  }
  // Obtain next sibling element
 } while ((element = element->nextSibling));  
}
```